# insert MySQL from two dates

Tags: php, mysql, date

so currently I have a form where a user can save the individual data (are shifts), based on the date that puts:

Example puts that on the day:

- 03/06/2017 etc ...
- 03/07/2017

So must manually enter each day what he did, but now I would like to give the opportunity for those who make a turn the same for several days, would not have to manually enter it by entering the start date and end date turn, it is made automatically.

I need that the inclusion in the database is single for each date. So if the user saves that made the absence from 2017-03-06 to 2017-03-09

In db, I have to find four lines:

```
1. 2017-03-06
2. 2017-03-07
3. 2017-03-08
4. 2017-03-09
```

you have any suggestions

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I try to explain my question

At the time except for a set of data through a form, being of work shifts, unless also the date in which it is done:

So if I go inside now I put 10.3.2017 etc ...
this is the query that I

$sql = "INSERT INTO db_mysql (value1,value2,value3)VALUES('$value1','$value2','$value3')

So save me a single row in db, If a user performs more equal shifts (such as a lack of it) I want to give the possibility that instead of individually enter each day, but starting from a given initial and final, enter the data in the database, increasing the initial date until the final, so if a user puts it did an absence from
3/10/2017 to 3/12/2017, I have to find the db 3 rows equal but with the date field increased:

03/10/2017
03/11/2017
12/03/2017

Comment: It may not be the most efficient way, but why not just do a loop in your application?

Comment: you can give me an example or direct me to some guide?

Comment: I still cannot quite understand the question. Are you trying to normalize the data?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display (which is, I think, essentially what this is) in your application level code.

Comment: I added more details in my first post

Answer (score 1):

You can add date in single field like 0000-00-01,0000-00-02 
When you fetch date you can use explode function of php if you are using php.

$str = "0000-00-01,0000-00-02";
$value=explode(",",$str));

now you can use both date by index.
like:
echo $value[0] // display 0000-00-01
echo $value[1] // display 0000-00-02

so you can use this method and no need to add new field for multiple date just add comma(,) between two date and insert it into your table field.

Answer (score 0):

You can take 2 fields for it startdate and enddate in table.
And you can easily fetch the data by simple query "select * from table where startdate='2017-03-07' and enddate='2017-03-10'";

Comment: I enter not extract data

Comment: i suggested that you can insert startdate and endate both in different field in db

Answer (score 0):

select * from table_name where date<='2017-03-17' and date>='2017-03-09'

Comment: I enter not extract data